# Push key, value to array: jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to added the following info to my array:  inserted_by_user_id -> 5

If I do a print_r on $array_post I get  data like this:

```
Array ( [saw_by_id] => 18 [appt_status_id] => 2 [reason_id] => 1 [pre_notes] => [howheard_id] => [marketing_event_id] => [start] => 2016-05-09T08:20:00+00:00 [end] => 2016-05-09T08:30:00+00:00 [allDay] => 0 [location_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 3102 [company_id] => 1 )
```

I'm trying to add the info like this:

```
// array_map should walk through $array - replaces blank values that are    serialized from the form and makes them null
 $array_post = array_map(function($value) {
    return !strlen($value) ? NULL : $value;
 }, $_POST); 

 $array_post.push({inserted_by_user_id: '5'});
```

I am using array_map on the array also to remove blanks before inserting into my DB.

When I try to use this push I get this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in THIS FILE on line 20
```

Line 20 is the line with .push on it.

If I don't use .push, everything works fine.  I just want to add that info to each array that's passed to this page.

Comment: `array_map` looks like PHP. `.push` looks like JavaScript. It seems that you're mixing up programming languages.

Comment: Oh my. You are correct. I had a moment here.  Forgive me.  I'll try to figure it out now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php you use. I just did an edit to try to make it a php question, as this is what language you are using

```
$array_post['inserted_by_user_id'] =  '5';
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for the prompt help. Thanks for changing this to a php related question, and sorry about that again.  I got it working with the above options.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use array_merge function and insert data into table -

```
$array_post = array_merge($array_post, array('inserted_by_user_id'=> '5'));
```

Comment: php 5.4 and > use `['inserted_by_user_id'=> '5']` instead of `array()`